# Estimating stochastic volatility shock for TFP

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, uncertainty, volatility-forecasting, macroeconomics

I am trying to estimate a stochastic volatility shock for Total Factor Productivity (TFP) in a similar way to Fernandez-Villaverde and Rubio-Ramírez (2010) and Fernandez-Villaverde et al. (2011).

$$A_t = \rho_{A}A_{t-1} + \sigma_t \epsilon_{A,t} $$

where $\epsilon_{A,t}$ is normally distributed with zero mean variance of 1.

From my understanding that $A_t$ is the Solow residual. To find $\rho_{A}$ this can be estimated with an ARIMA(1,0,0) and time trend where $\rho$ will be the coefficient and $\sigma_t$ is the standard deviation of the residuals. Is this correct?

Regarding the stochastic volatility

$$\log (\sigma_t) = (1 - \rho_\sigma)\log \sigma + \rho_\sigma \log \sigma_{t-1}+ \eta \, u_t$$

Where $\sigma_t$ is time varying stochastic volatility, $\rho_\sigma$ is the autoregressive coefficient of the log standard deviation and $\eta$ is
the standard deviation of the innovations to volatility.

Can someone please tell me how I can estimate the equation of the stochastic volatility? How can I have a series for $\sigma_t$ ?